import() uses relative path to load module the first time resulting in 404
I have a Vue 3 app built with TypeScript.  I am using import() to dynamically load modules based on a parameter, in this case a language code.
I only ever make one call to load the module, but the browser shows 2 requests for each file included in the module I am trying to load.  The first request a is relative URL 'chunks/file.js', the second request uses an absolute URL '/app/chunks/file.js'.
The app works because the files get loaded the second time, but how can I prevent loading with the incorrect URL the first time?
More Info:
/src/languages/languagefeatures.ts:
    private featureTypes: any = {
        es: () => import('./es/LanguageFeaturesEs'),
        ja: () => 
            {
               console.log("import is being invoked: ./ja/LanguageFeaturesJa");
               return import('./ja/LanguageFeaturesJa');        
            }
 

Looking at the compiled code, this is generated:
constructor() {
    R(this, "featureTypes", {
        es: ()=>ks(()=>import("./LanguageFeaturesEs.js"), []),
        ja: ()=>(console.log("import is being invoked: ./ja/LanguageFeaturesJa"),
        ks(()=>import("./LanguageFeaturesJa.js"), ["chunks/LanguageFeaturesJa.js", "chunks/GlyphPitch.js"]))
    });
    R(this, "loadedFeatureTypes", {})
}



What is ks? What exactly are you using as your build tool and how is it configured to bundle modules?

Vite, I don't know the inner workings of how the code is bundled and minified or why it's named ks.  It returns a promise.

@Brian You could start with disabling minification then, this would give some clue. It's hard to impossible to debug minified code on paper.

That's not a bad idea.  Reviewing the Vite and Vue source code could also give me a better understanding of what is going wrong.  It would be a pretty big effort so I was hoping someone familiar with Vite/Vue might have come across this and have a solution.

This looks pretty similar to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78983969/how-to-set-vite-config-for-dynamic-imports-code-splitting-when-entry-file-and
Any solution found?
